# Infinite sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k+1}{4k}$

Tags: summation, products

Here I have this sum,
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n \dfrac{2k+1}{4k}$.

I have no idea how to sum this up.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Start by simplifying the summand by writing the product in terms of factorials and try to notice the connection of the summand to ${-3/2 \choose n}$. Then consider the power-series of $(1 - 4 x)^{-3/2} - 1$.

Comment: Please [avoid "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). They do not make good quality questions and are likely to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Is this true:
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{4k}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n2k+1}{\prod_{k=1}^n4k}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n2k+1}{4^n\prod_{k=1}^nk}=\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{4^n\Gamma(n)}$$

EDIT
as pointed out by another user:
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n2k+1}{4^n\prod_{k=1}^nk}=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{4^nn!}$$

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with Gamma function.

Comment: I am familiar with it but not in this context, so I need someone else to verify that this is true

Comment: $\prod_{k=1}^n (2k + 1) = (2n + 1)(2n - 1) \cdots 3 \cdot 1 = (2n + 1)!! = \frac{(2n + 2)!}{2^{n + 1}(n + 1)!}$ and $\prod_{k = 1}^n k = n! = \Gamma(n + 1)$.